# problem with guid, when i change the folder name

Tags: site-url, guids

I'm new to WordPress. I started the site as good with folder name `wordpress`. After I changed the folder name from `wordpress` to `test`. And also change the **siteurl** from `http://localhost/wordpress` to `http://localhost/test` in wp_options table. And I modified the **guid** with this [refer](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Important_GUID_Note).

My problem is, still I click any 'post' or 'comment', that goes to `http://localhost/wordpress/?p=7#respond` page only. I want that's goes to `http://localhost/test/?p=7#respond`.

Anyone can?

Comment: have you re-saved your permalink settings?

Comment: The GUID is not used for permalinks, it isn’t even an URL (just happens to look like one).

Comment: @toscho i got your point. thanks. and thanks david.binda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing siteurl, Go to admin panel and update permalink structure once and check.It will start working with new folder name.

Hope it helps

Comment: but, I didn't change 'Site Address (URL)' in admin panel> Setting>General.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) page in the Codex.

> When your domain name or URLs change - i.e. from http://example.com/blog to http://example.com, or http://example.com to http://newexample.com - there are additional concerns. The files and database can be moved, however references to the old domain name or location will remain in the database, and that can cause issues with links or theme display.

There is a special script, [Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).

> If you are a developer, use this option.

Run this script to safely change all database instances.

Answer (score 0):

Try resaving permalink setting and Instead of manually changing url you can change it by using this [serach and replace wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/).

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `home` field to `http://localhost/test` too in your `wp_options` table.